# Перевод списка в словарь

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть список, который достал из файла. Хочу его перевести в словарь у которого ключом будет фамилия, а значением будет список с именем и телефоном.

```
['Sergeev', 'Artem', '+70000000000', 'Ivanova', 'Anna', '+70000000000', 'Sidorova', 'Arina', '+70000000000', 'Gavrilov', 'Vitalik', '+70000000000', 'Petrov', 'Viktor', '+70000000000', '']
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Элементы в исходном списке образуют группы по 3 штуки. Соответственно, удобно пустить цикл с шагом 3, записывая эти группы в словарь нужным способом:

```
source = [
    'Sergeev', 'Artem', '+70000000000',
    'Ivanova', 'Anna', '+70000000000',
    'Sidorova', 'Arina', '+70000000000',
    'Gavrilov', 'Vitalik', '+70000000000',
    'Petrov', 'Viktor', '+70000000000',
]

result = dict()
for i in range(0, len(source), 3):
    result[source[i]] = (source[i+1], source[i+2])

print(result)
```

Результат:

```
{
    'Sergeev': ('Artem', '+70000000000'),
    'Ivanova': ('Anna', '+70000000000'),
    'Sidorova': ('Arina', '+70000000000'),
    'Gavrilov': ('Vitalik', '+70000000000'),
    'Petrov': ('Viktor', '+70000000000')
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! Оказывается ходил вокруг да около.

Answer (score 2):

```
source = ['Sergeev', 'Artem', '+70000000001', 'Ivanova', 'Anna', '+70000000002', 'Sidorova', 'Arina', '+70000000003', 'Gavrilov', 'Vitalik', '+70000000004', 'Petrov', 'Viktor', '+70000000005', ]

# iter
it = iter(source)
result = {fam: [next(it), next(it)] for fam in it}
print(result)  # {'Sergeev': ['Artem', '+70000000001'], ...

# slice
zp = zip(source[::3], source[1::3], source[2::3])
result = {fam: [name, tel] for (fam, name, tel) in zp}
print(result)  # {'Sergeev': ['Artem', '+70000000001'], ...
```